# Jackson: "Can not set final" when deserializing Java record with @JsonUnwrapped annotation

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, java-record

I have a simple Java record with a traditional POJO for the Address class. Serialization works as expected, but deserialization fails with the error message "Can not set final"

```
public record TestRecord(String name, @JsonUnwrapped Address address) {}
```

Serializing this works fine.

```
Address address = new Address();
address.setCity("New York");
address.setState("NY");
TestRecord rec = new TestRecord("Bob", address);

JsonMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
jsonMapper.writeValueAsString(rec); // {"name":"Bob","city":"New York","state":"NY"}
```

But deserializing throws an exception:

```
@Test
void should_DeserializeUnwrappedRecord() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity("New York");
    address.setState("NY");
    TestRecord expectedRecord = new TestRecord("Bob", address);

    String json = """
            {"name":"Bob","city":"New York","state":"NY"}""";

    JsonMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
    TestRecord actualValue = jsonMapper.readValue(json, TestRecord.class);
    assertEquals(expectedRecord, actualValue);
}
```

Exception:

```
    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not set final org.example.AppTest$Address field org.example.AppTest$TestRecord.address to org.example.AppTest$Address
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; byte offset: #UNKNOWN]

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:276)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set final org.example.AppTest$Address field org.example.AppTest$TestRecord.address to org.example.AppTest$Address
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwFinalFieldIllegalAccessException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:80)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeQualifiedObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:799)
```

If I were to change TestRecord to a plain Java class it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create specific TestRecord constructor which takes 3 String values and then calls the canonical constructor of the TestRecord class. This new constructor needs to have @JsonCreator annotation in order to instruct Jackson to use it when deserializing.

```
 public record Address(String city, String state) {   }

 public record TestRecord(String name, Address address) {

        @JsonCreator
        public TestRecord(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("city") String city, @JsonProperty("state") String state) {
            this(name, new Address(city, state));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Surprisingly this did not work either. I'm getting the same error. I recently listened to a podcast regarding records and simplifying JSON was one of the use cases for the record pattern. I've found very little practical use case for records in my own code, but JSON is the one area I can see it being useful. But if we have to go through a bunch of hoops to serialize/deserialize (adding special constructors just for basic wrapper classes) it defeats the purpose of using records in the first place!

Comment: which version of Jackson are you using? and which version on Java? I tested this solution with jackson 2.14.2 and java 19. The assertion went smoothly green. And yes I completely agree with you, adding this constructor is not elegant solution. Just the purpose of record class is to have fields final so you cannot do it any other way around than initializing the state once and only once in the beginning. You cannot use any setter methods.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken that does work. I had accidentally left the `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation on the Address parameter, e.g. `record TestRecord(String name, @JsonUnwrapped Address address)`. Once I removed that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `TestRecord` is a record which means all of its fields are final. So you cannto deserialise the JSON to this object using default configuration.

I think you have two options to do that:

1. Mark every field with JsonProperty

```
 public record TestRecord(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonUnwrapped Address address) {}
 public record Address(@JsonProperty("city") String city, @JsonProperty("state") String state) {}
```

2. Change field visibility level for Jackson using:

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public record TestRecord(String name, @JsonUnwrapped Address address) {}
```

Comment: I tried both of those options and it's still failing with the same error message.